# Estimating the intercepts and slopes for three treatments

Tags: r, regression, anova, dummy-variable

Let's assume that my data looks this ( it is just data to illustrate my question):

```
set.seed(1234)
x=runif(12, 22,28);x
y=runif(12,88,120);y

y1=y[1:4];y1
y2=y[5:8];y2
y3=y[9:12];y3

x1=x[1:4];x1
x2=x[5:8];x2
x3=x[9:12];x3

dat= cbind(y1,x1,y2,x2,y3,x3);dat

            y1       x1        y2       x2        y3       x3
    [1,] 118.72718 27.79948 100.56455 23.59740  95.37221 25.51741
    [2,]  90.46189 26.12509  94.38618 27.96536 103.42347 24.44862
    [3,]  92.48808 25.67335 108.15713 24.08918 108.85686 26.52390
    [4,] 103.06760 25.84996 108.88237 26.37924 103.26130 22.05003
```

Let assume that (y1,x1) represents treatment 1, (y2,x2) represents treatment 2, and (y3,x3) represent treatment 3. My goals are to estimate the intercepts and slopes (using an incremental design). Then, determine the hypothesis matrix (the null hypothesis that all slopes are the same).

I was thinking that I could use indicators. Like for x1= 1 if treatment, and 0 otherwise. Then x2= 1 if treatment 2, and 0 otherwise. Here is otherwise refers to the third treatment.

Here is what I come up with:

```
    X< as.matrix(cbind(rep(1,12),c(rep(1,4),rep(0,8)),c(rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(0,4))))
```

Anyway, I do not know where to go from here. I was wondering if someone would give me something to get started. Please, all notation should be in matrix forms. Thank you!

Edit: I am trying to do it in matrix notation, here is what I got so far, though I am having some coefficients as NA:

```
set.seed(1234)
x=runif(12, 22,28);x
y=runif(12,88,120);y

y1=y[1:4];y1
y2=y[5:8];y2
y3=y[9:12];y3

x1=x[1:4];x1
x2=x[5:8];x2
x3=x[9:12];x3

dat= cbind(y1,x1,y2,x2,y3,x3);dat



 X1<- cbind( dat[,2],rep(0,4),rep(0,4), dat[,2],rep(1,4),rep(1,4));X1
 X2 <- cbind(dat[,4],rep(1,4),dat[,4], rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(1,4));X2
 X3 <- cbind(dat[,6],rep(1,4),dat[,6], rep(0,4),rep(0,4),rep(0,4));X3

 X <- rbind(X1,X2,X3)

 model <- lm(formula = y ~ X);summary(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the second part, you can accomplish what you are looking to do by binding your y and x values with a third 'categorical' variable which tells the trial to which it belongs.

Then stack them in a single three column data frame, label the columns to keep straight your variables and row bind them together.

Make sure your numbers were not categorized in binding (as mine were).

Then you can do a linear regression

```
one<- cbind(y1,x1,'one')
two<- cbind(y2, x2, 'two')
three<- cbind(y3, x3,'three')

dat<- data.frame(rbind(one, two, three))
colnames(dat)<- c('y', 'x', 'treatment')
dat$y<-as.numeric(dat$y) #binding tweaked numerics to categories
dat$x<-as.numeric(dat$x) #I converted them back
model <- lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x + treatment, data = dat)
```

Then your output is as follows:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x + treatment, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4579 -2.2156 -0.4115  1.5442  6.6039 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
x               -0.1461     0.4283  -0.341   0.7418  
treatmentone     7.9185     3.9775   1.991   0.0817 .
treatmentthree   8.0112     2.5156   3.185   0.0129 *
treatmenttwo     6.4185     3.9775   1.614   0.1453  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.04 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7991,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6986 
F-statistic: 7.954 on 4 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.006839
```

By spelling out the formula with a zero, you get the influence of x plus an effect for each of the coefficients.

Each beta is an intercept adjustment for a treatment the x-coefficient is a shared slope.

EDIT in accord with Roland's Suggestion, this will give you individual slopes.

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + treatment, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4579 -2.2156 -0.4115  1.5442  6.6039 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      7.9185     3.9775   1.991   0.0817 .
x               -0.1461     0.4283  -0.341   0.7418  
treatmentthree   0.0927     3.4463   0.027   0.9792  
treatmenttwo    -1.5000     2.8570  -0.525   0.6138  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.04 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08671,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2558 
F-statistic: 0.2532 on 3 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.857
```

Comment: Don't suppress the intercept and include the interaction to allow different slopes: `y ~ x * treatment`

Comment: It means that by including the intercept, you get an intercept as listed above, and then a slope for X and a coefficient for each LEVEL of the category. Because they are mutually exclusive categories the Beta value for the other two go to zero when multiplied by a binary variable You have to think of this as though each of the category levels were a dummy column, with a 1 for the proper category and zero for the other two. You end up with an X coefficient  and a category constant adjustment to the y-intercept.

Comment: You can stack the X variables as I did above and it will work fine. You cannot use a traditional matrix with the categories, you need to convert them to dummies , two columns with 0, 1 to do so. The best method is to use `lm() and let R manage the matrix math.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model frame d (from the data in the Note at the end):

```
d <- with(DF, data.frame(y = c(y1, y2, y3), x = c(x1, x2, x3), g = gl(3, 4)))
```

and then run regressions for separate intercepts and slopes vs. separate intercepts with same slope.  Finally use `anova` to perform the test.

```
fm1 <- lm(y ~ g + x:g + 0, d) # separate intercepts & slopes
coef(fm1)
##           g1           g2           g3         g1:x         g2:x         g3:x 
## -201.0983992  141.2889141   94.7617449   11.4666919   -1.5011629    0.3233902 

fm2 <- lm(y ~ g + x + 0, d) # separate intercepts, same slope
coef(fm2)
##         g1         g2         g3          x 
## 83.5468017 85.9297193 86.2446353  0.6691224 

anova(fm1, fm2)
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ g + x/g + 0
Model 2: y ~ g + x + 0
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)  
1      6 330.52                             
2      8 723.85 -2   -393.33 3.5701 0.0952 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

so p = 0.0952 and the two models are not significantly different, i.e. the slopes are not significantly different from each other at the 5% level.

### Note

The assumed input is:

```
Lines <- "
       y1       x1        y2       x2        y3       x3
118.72718 27.79948 100.56455 23.59740  95.37221 25.51741
 90.46189 26.12509  94.38618 27.96536 103.42347 24.44862
 92.48808 25.67335 108.15713 24.08918 108.85686 26.52390
103.06760 25.84996 108.88237 26.37924 103.26130 22.05003"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```